# How to display hard coded pages links dynamically when customizing laravel pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

I'm not sure if I've phrased my question properly but I'm customizing pagination and so far I have this in my view and it's working well.

```
@if($paginator->hasPages())
<div class="pagination">
    @if ($paginator->currentPage() > 1)
    <a href="">&laquo;</a>
    @else
    <a href="" style="opacity:0.5; pointer-events:none;">&laquo;</a>
    @endif


    <a class="active" href="">1</a>
    <a href="">2</a>
    <a href="">3</a>
    <a href="">4</a>
    <a href="">5</a>


    @if (!$paginator->hasMorePages())
        <a href="" style="opacity:0.5; pointer-events:none;">&raquo;</a>
    @else
    <a href="">&raquo;</a>
    @endif

</div>
@endif
```

As you can see the pages links are hard coded. How do I display them dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing all that with

```
@if($paginator->hasPages())
    {!! $paginator->render(); !!}
@endif
```

you can also

```html
@if($paginator->hasPages())
<div class="pagination">
    @if ($paginator->currentPage() > 1)
    <a href="{{$paginator->previousPageUrl()}}">&laquo;</a>
    @else
    <a href="{{$paginator->url(1)}}" style="opacity:0.5; pointer-events:none;">&laquo;</a>
    @endif

    @if($paginator->currentPage()-2 >0)
    <a href="{{$paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()-2)}}">{{$paginator->currentPage()-2}}</a>
    @endif
    @if($paginator->currentPage()-1 >0)
    <a href="{{$paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()-1)}}">{{$paginator->currentPage()-1}}</a>
    @endif
    <a class="active" href="#">{{$paginator->currentPage()}}</a>
    @if($paginator->currentPage()+1 <=$paginator->lastPage())
    <a href="{{$paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+1)}}">{{$paginator->currentPage()+1}}</a>
    @endif
    @if($paginator->currentPage()+2 <=$paginator->lastPage())
    <a href="{{$paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+2)}}">{{$paginator->currentPage()+2}}</a>
    @endif



    @if (!$paginator->hasMorePages())
        <a href="{{$paginator->url($paginator->lastPage())}}" style="opacity:0.5; pointer-events:none;">&raquo;</a>
    @else
    <a href="{{$paginator->nextPageUrl()}}">&raquo;</a>
    @endif

</div>
@endif
```

This code is not clean 100% but you get the idea (especialy aroud the `$paginator->hasMorePages()`).

Comment: 1. What code exactly was I to replace with using the first solution? The hard coded code?

2. The second solution works now I'd like to understand how it works. How is this ```@if($paginator->currentPage()-2 >0)``` read and what is it doing?

Comment: @AlphyGacheru  it's an equation, current page minus 2 supérior to 0 so you dont have a -1 page button. for the first solution, replace EVERYTHING with that.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. How to implement styles for the first option? It works but doesn't look nice.

Comment: @AlphyGacheru rework the css, once its done you can use it everywhere where you use a pagination. but if you want something ready, it is compatible with bootstrap css https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files